# How does matrix multiplication work when you have two parenthesis of two calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How do I calculate the following example:
$$(\lambda A-I)(\lambda A-I)$$

where A is any $n\,x\,n$ matrix of the same size as $I$? Do I multiply as regular algebra or what?

Is is:
$$(\lambda A)^2-2\lambda A + I$$

Why, why not?

Edit:
Or for the example
$$(A-2BC)(A-2BC)$$

where $A, B, C$ are three $3\,x\,3$ matrices.

Comment: It does work that way for this example. However usually one needs to note not all matrices obey $AB=BA$. So for instance, if I have $A, B$ matrices, $(A+B)^2$ is not usually $A^2+2AB+B^2$, rather, we would have $A^2+AB+BA+B^2$

Comment: The reason I am asking is because in my textbook one of the equations is solved by simply multiplying the left side parts with the right parenthesis: (A-B)(A-B) = A(A-B) -B(A-B)

Comment: For the edited example it would be $A^2-2BCA-2ABC+4B^2C^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is distributive but since order matters you have to be careful not to commute any of the elements. Lets look at the example $(A-B)(C-D)$ since it's more general and assume all the matrices are square. We can do this two ways. First we can calculate $$(A-B)(C-D)=(A-B)C -(A-B)D=\\AC-BC-(AD-BD)=AC-BC-AD+BD$$

Or we could have distributed the other way with $$(A-B)(C-D)=A(C-D)-B(C-D)=\\AC-AD-(BC-BD)=AC-AD-BC+BD$$

And we can see by inspection that they are the same regardless of our choice in left or right distributivity.

Comment: Ahhh yes, now I can see how he got $A(C-D)-B(C-D)$, I went one step too far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Small note: it doesn't change anything if these matrices are not square, as long as they are of the right sizes for the operations to be defined. (And if they are in any of these expressions, they also are in all the others.)

Comment: I am also confused about: $(AA^t)(AA^t)=A(A^tA)A^t=A(I)A^t=AA^t$, is this actually correct?

Comment: @linker $A^tA=I$ is only true if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Remember how matrix multiplication is defined:

Given a matrices $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ of size $m\times n$ and $n \times p$, we define the product $\mathbf C = \mathbf {AB}$ as the matrix of size $m \times p$, whose entries, $c_{ij}$ are given by the dot product between the $i$th row of $\mathbf A$ and the $j$th column of $\mathbf B$.

That is

$$
c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{ik}b_{kj}.
$$

Using this definition, we can satisfy ourselves that matrix multiplication does distribute over addition. Given matrices $\mathbf{L}$, $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{N}$, of suitable sizes, the product $\mathbf{L}(\mathbf M + \mathbf{N})$ will have coefficients given by

$$ \sum_k l_{ik}(m_{kj} + n_{kj}) = \sum_k l_{ik}m_{kj} + \sum_k l_{ik}n_{kj}$$

The two terms on the right are the coefficients of $\mathbf {LM}$ and $\mathbf{LN}$ respectively, and we conclude that $\mathbf{L}(\mathbf M + \mathbf{N}) = \mathbf{L}\mathbf M + \mathbf{L}\mathbf{N}$